# List of tuples deletion

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples like

```
[(1,1),(2,1),(2,2),(5,2),(5,6)]
```

How do I get

```
[(1,1),(2,2),(5,6)]
```

If left side of tuple is same only the right side largest of tuple is retained
If some tuples have the same left value then the tuple with greatest right value should be in list other tuples which do not have same left(first) values to compete with should remain as they are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need collections or any fancy library. Let's say we have a list of tuples like this (which is a bit messier than your own example):

```
listt = [(8, 1),(1, 1),(2, 1),(2, 2),(5, 2),(5, 6)]
```

For convenience, I'd rather first sort the list based on the first elements of the tuples:

```
listt = sorted(listt,key=lambda x: x[0])
# Now we have [(1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2), (5, 2), (5, 6), (8, 1)]
```

Now in each group of tuples that have the same first elements, we only need to pick up the last element. Because of the way the list is sorted, we would end up with tuples that have the largest second element:

```
new_listt = []
elem_0 = listt[0][0]

for i in range(len(listt)-1):
    if listt[i+1][0] != elem_0:
        new_listt.append(listt[i])
        elem_0 = listt[i+1][0]

#We have to also account for the last element     
new_listt.append(listt[i+1])
```

We can check to see if it works:

```
print(listt)
print("====")
print(new_listt)
```

In my example it gives back `[(1, 1), (2, 2), (5, 6), (8, 4)]` and with `listt = [(2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (5, 1)]` it gives `[(2, 3), (3, 1), (5, 1)]` which I assume is correct.

Comment: As a more efficient way you can use `operator.itemgetter` instead of calling a `lambda` in `sorted`. `sorted(listt,key=itemgetter(0))`

Answer (score 3):

What you envisioning can easily be achieved by **sorting your items and removing the duplicates**. Note, as you are dealing with pair tuples, **removing duplicates** here indicates **removing pairs with same first element**. **Sorting** the elements in **ascending** would any way would order the elements such that **if two pairs have same first item, the pair with larger second item would follow the other**.

Note, python dict/set do not follow any definite ordering, so it is important to **use ordered dict**

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> lst = [(1,1),(2,1),(2,2),(5,2),(5,6)]
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(lst)).items()
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (5, 6)]
>>> lst = [(2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (5, 1)]
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(lst)).items()
[(2, 3), (3, 1), (5, 1)]
```

Another approach though a bit convoluted is to use groupby. Which of them is better is subjective and would require performance comparison.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> lst =  [(2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (5, 1)]
>>> [max(v) for k, v in groupby(sorted(lst), key = itemgetter(0))]
[(2, 3), (3, 1), (5, 1)]
>>> lst = [(1,1),(2,1),(2,2),(5,2),(5,6)]
>>> [max(v) for k, v in groupby(sorted(lst), key = itemgetter(0))]
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (5, 6)]
```